# Define a matrix template with using

Tags: c++

I want to define a matrix with `using` keyword to use templates.

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
using row = std::vector<T>;

template<typename T>
using Mat = std::vector<row> >;
```

I think this definition is ok, but I don't know how to instantiate now the matrix.
I tried with `Mat<int> m(3, row<int>(3));`, but It wont work.
Any clues on how to instantiate it?

Comment: I think this worked: [https://ideone.com/KS7Vm8](https://ideone.com/KS7Vm8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have small typos, it should be

```
template <typename T>
using row = std::vector<T>;

template<typename T>
using Mat = std::vector<row<T>>;

int main() {
    [[maybe_unused]] Mat<int> m(3, row<int>(3));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/106ae0f82ba46512)

Comment: This is correct, although OP should be aware it's a terrible way to represent a matrix since the memory is discontiguous and worst of all, it could easily become non-rectangular. Use a library like Eign if you want to do linear algebra.

Comment: @Ben I would use a sparse representation for this, but I was curious about this approach with templates

Comment: Yeah, your question is reasonable, particularly for understanding templated `using` declarations, but for production linear algebra, you want to use a library (which itself will be templated, most likely). In the case of `Eigen`, it supports both statically-shaped and dynamically-shaped 1D and 2D matrices.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
template <typename T>
using Mat = std::vector<std::vector<T>>;

int main()
{
    Mat<int> a;
}
```